# ex = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Tags: asp.net

I understand that if you put a Response.Redirect inside a try-catch that you're going to get this error unless you specify the 2nd param of the redirect as false.

But even looking at this article ([PRB: ThreadAbortException Occurs If You Use Response.End, Response.Redirect, or Server.Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/)) I still don't understand why I have to set this to false for this particular line of code...we've always had true for that param until I wrapped that in a try-catch:

```
Response.Redirect(SecureUrl("Confirmation", SessionID), true);
```

We want to close it because it's the end of the line..the confirmation page.  But when this is wrapped in the try-catch I get that error.  I just want to understand better why false.  I read the article and it doesn't jump out at me.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `true` as the second parameter, it will throw a `ThreadAbortException` to stop processing the request.

Code inside of ASP.Net will catch the `ThreadAbortException`, call `Thread.ResetAbort`, and send the (HTTP 301) response.

If you have a `catch` block, you will also see the `ThreadAbortException`, just as you'd see any other exception.

The best thing for you to do is to add an empty catch block for `ThreadAbortException` before your catch block, like this:

```
} catch(ThreadAbortException) { throw; }
```